# Last digits using Euler's theorem

Tags: analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Euler's theorem says:

$$a^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$

Find $$22^{41} \pmod{10}$$

Obviously, you have to gun for $\varphi(10)$.

Let $a = 22$

$$22^{\varphi{10}} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

But what should I do?

Comment: You got it wrong, the theorem works only when a and m are coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this is to use Chinese Remainder Theorem in combination with Euler's theorem.

Clearly, $22^{41} \equiv 0 \pmod 2$. $22^{41} \equiv 2^{41} \pmod 5 = (2^4)^{10} \times 2 \pmod 5 = 2 \pmod 5$ using Euler's theorem. Combining the two results using CRT, we obtain $22^{41} \equiv 2 \pmod {10}$.

Answer (score 0):

We must find the congruence $\bmod 5$ and $\bmod 2$.The congruence $\bmod 2$ is $0$.

Since $22\equiv 2\bmod 5$ and $\varphi(5)=4$ we get:

$22^{41}\equiv2^{41}=2^{40}\cdot1=(2^{4})^{19}\cdot2\equiv1\cdot2=2$.

Therefore $22^{41}\equiv 2\bmod 5$ and $0\bmod 2$.

So $22^{41}\equiv 2\bmod 10$